# downside to --debug-init option of Emacs?

Tags: emacs, debug

If I modify the dotemacs file, it may introduce an error. Without `--debug-init` option, emacs does not invoke debugger on error while processing dotemacs. Because I modify dotemacs often, I edited my Emacs shortcut (on MS Windows) to include the --debug-init option in the shortcut. Is there any downside to this? If not, why is this option an opt-in instead of an opt-out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html#Error-Debugging) explains this nicely:

> entry to the debugger is not a normal consequence of an error. Many commands signal Lisp errors when invoked inappropriately, and during ordinary editing it would be very inconvenient to enter the debugger each time this happens.

I think the key point is that errors are not normal when just using emacs. You'll probably only enable debugging when you've broken your config, are developing emacs lisp code, or when when you've found a bug in someone else's code that you want to help debug.

Comment: I think you mean "errors _are_  normal when just using emacs"